# Difference between $\mathbb{T}^n$ and $S^n$ and applications to dynamics (Euler angles and configuration manifolds)

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, dynamical-systems

I am struggling to see the difference between the $n$-sphere and the $n$-torus. We define $\mathbb{T}^n = S^1 \times S^1 \times \cdots \times S^1$, where the Cartesian product is taken $n$ times.

I guess we should start with low dimensions and work our way up. If $n=1$, then the two manifolds are not just topologically equivalent, but they are geometrically equivalent. They are the same mathematical object.

Now let $n=2$. Both the 2-sphere and the 2-torus may be charted out by two angular coordinates. The difference to me is that the torus has both angles going from $0$ to $2\pi$ while the sphere has one angle going from $0$ to $2\pi$ and another going from $0$ to $\pi$. Is there an example where one is more beneficial than the other?

In dynamics, if I have a 2-segment pendulum in the plane parametrized by two angles, then I may represent the configuration manifold as a 2-torus since both angles range up to $2\pi$. Would a single segment pendulum with two degrees of freedom be an example of a configuration manifld that is a 2-sphere?

Now let's investigate $n = 3$. Consider the topological group $SO(3)$. We may chart out $SO(3)$ with Euler angles. The first and last angles range from $0$ to $2\pi$ while the middle angle ranges from $0$ to $\pi$. What sort of a topological object would this be associated with?

I can see that if we make a cut around the 2-torus and throw out a ring from the middle, we may identify edges and get a 2-sphere. Can a similar thing be done with the 3-torus and the 3-sphere?

Thanks.

Comment: The $n$-torus is what you get when you take a cube and identify opposite sides. The $n$-sphere is (topologically) what you get when you take an $n$-cube and collapse the boundary to a point. I think that's what you're looking for in your last paragraph.

Comment: Regarding $SO(3)$ --- $SO(3)$ is a 3-sphere with antipodal points identified.

Comment: You can easily reparameterize either the 2-sphere or the 2-torus so that your parameters range from anything you like to anything you like, so the parameterizations you're quoting are of no significance here.  One key difference between a sphere and a torus is that if you cut a circle out of a sphere, you must disconnect it, whereas you can cut a circle out of a torus without disconnecting it.

Comment: Could you please state as clearly and succintly as possible your question? If you feel like the comments you made and how you got to the problem are useful informations, can you just make a clear separation from them and the question itself?